# New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : Access to the path 'C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\ARM\storage.json' is denied

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-code, deployment, azure-resource-manager

I want to create ARM template but access is denied.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/viz1f.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try running the same PowerShell cmdlet `New-azresoucegroupdeployment`" in a new PowerShell session in admin mode.
- The issue is the current powershell might be running in  non admin mode and it does access to read the files that were present in c drive.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I tried running it in the admin mode, didn't help. Any other suggestion?